# ByteBuffer vs. Buffer on Datagram Packets

Tags: java, networking, garbage-collection, sockets

I've read that ByteBuffer (java.nio) should be used over the Buffer class for reading in data simply because it's more efficient (?). My question revolves around a UDP client that reads packets from a multicast address and processes them into primitive objects. What is the most efficient/fastest way to parse these packets from a DatagramSocket? Right now, I have a datagram packet whose byte array I wrap a ByteBuffer around and read from there. My goal is to minimize new object creation and maximize speed.

Comment: I think this question would be better suited to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4):

A `DatagramSocket` cannot read directly into a `ByteBuffer`, but you can do this using a `DatagramChannel` instead.

Comment: A DatagramSocket _can_ receive directly into a ByteBuffer (if by "directly" you mean zero-copy). You create a DatagramPacket that wraps a ByteBuffer. You can receive() and then read the data out of the ByteBuffer. Same for packet construction and send().

Comment: @charstar, I don't think that is correct.  The `DatagramPacket` constructors all take a `byte[]`, not a `ByteBuffer`.  You can take the backing array of the buffer only if it has one, and a *direct* byte buffer will not have one.

Answer (score 0):

I think ByteBuffer is to be used just because Buffer does not have enough functionality to make access efficient from programmer's point of view, not from efficiency. I doubt there is difference in efficiency as underlying code is mostly duplicate.

Note tho that whether either is more efficient than using simple byte arrays is not always clear -- NIO performance is easy to misestimate.